# how to Call a Logoff in jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

*how to call a Logoff action from client side i have written this code but 
it gives me an error of 404*

here is the code

```
location.href = '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")';
```

Comment: Have you written `'@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")';` in a JS file?

Comment: Do you have Account controller and LogOff action in your code?

Comment: yes i did both of them but my action method is of post

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `HttpPost` method to `HttpGet` method in your `AccountController`, or implement both if required

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        WebSecurity.Logout();
        Session.Clear();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOff(FormCollection c)
    {
        WebSecurity.Logout();
        Session.Clear();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this gives an error because you used the same signature for both methods?